# history plugin for complex javascript manipulated page

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser-history

I've made page where are a lot of different links and buttons all manipulated through ajax requests. After getting replys from server side I change content of several different divs. So the page URL is always the same.

Is there any kind of plugin or tool that will remember the state of all divs and will act on back forward browser pressed buttons ? If yes please post links which u have

Comment: I would suggest to use a MVC framework sucj BackboneJS, JavascriptMVC and use the Router of those frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Crossroads.js](http://millermedeiros.github.com/crossroads.js/) (client-side routing) and [Hasher](https://github.com/millermedeiros/Hasher) (controling browser history). These plugins work well together.

Another option would be to use a MVC library like [backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/). It already includes a router component.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use hash tag navigation or HTML 5 history, for this to work properly you best start using a JavaScript MVC framework.

Check [this page](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/) for a demo from several JS MVC frameworks:

I would recommend using backbone.js, as I believe it might blow your mind.
The demos on the link I gave you don't include code for using backbone.js for your specific need, you will want to be looking at the backbone JS router.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router

Answer (score 0):

[Pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) is a nice solution, but, like most pushState approaches, not supported in all browsers yet (most notably, IE < 10 not supported)

However, pjax is lightweight, direct, and simple to implement. In the browsers that do support pushState, with little extra work you'll get the solution you're looking for